# Drop Rows of an id after a particular column value in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a dataset like:

```
Id   Status

1     0
1     0
1     0
1     0
1     1
2     0
1     0
2     0
3     0
3     0
```

I want to drop all rows of an id after its status became 1, i.e. my new dataset will be:

```
Id   Status

1     0
1     0
1     0
1     0
1     1
2     0
2     0
3     0
3     0

i.e.

1     0   --> gets removed since this row appears after id 1 already had a status of 1
```

How to implement it efficiently since I have a very large (200 GB+) dataset.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your ID is not unique, and you don´t have a way to keep the order, like a time-key.

Comment: @DanielSobrado yes, my id is not unique, i have a time-key but it is also not unique

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**: Revisiting this question a month later, there is actually a much simpler way with `groupby` and `cumsum`: Just group by `Id` and take the `cumsum` of `Status`, then drop the values where the `cumsum` is more than 0:

```
df[df.groupby('Id')['Status'].cumsum() < 1]
```

The best way I have found is to find the index of the first 1 and slice each group that way. In cases where no 1 exists, return the group unchanged:

```
def remove(series):
    indexless = series.reset_index(drop=True)
    ones = indexless[indexless['Status'] == 1]
    if len(ones) > 0:
        return indexless.iloc[:ones.index[0] + 1]

    else:
        return indexless

df.groupby('Id').apply(remove).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
   Id  Status
0   1       0
1   1       0
2   1       0
3   1       0
4   1       1
5   2       0
6   2       0
7   3       0
8   3       0
```

Comment: i still need the 1     1 row... (rows for id 1 after that have to be dropped)

Comment: @tstseby just need to add 1 to the `iloc` index (edited answer)

Answer (score 2):

Here's an idea;

You can create a dict with the first index where the status is 1 for each ID (assuming the DataFrame is sorted by ID):

```
d = df.loc[df["Status"]==1].drop_duplicates()
d = dict(zip(d["Id"], d.index))
```

Then you create a column with the first `status=1` for each Id:

```
df["first"] = df["Id"].map(d)
```

Finally you drop every row where the index is less than than the `first` column:

```
df = df.loc[df.index<df["first"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `groupby` with `cumsum` to find where status is `1`.

```
res = df.groupby('Id', group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x[x.Status.cumsum() > 0])
res

    Id  Status
4   1   1
6   1   0
```

Exclude index that `Status==0`.

```
not_select_id = res[res.Status==0].index

df[~df.index.isin(not_select_id)]

Id  Status
0   1   0
1   1   0
2   1   0
3   1   0
4   1   1
5   2   0
7   2   0
8   3   0
9   3   0
```